# Not continuing after calling driver.get() in Python Selenium

Tags: python

Thanks for the help, I have a problem when I try to run the driver.get as it stays there and continues with the execution of the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service as IEService

ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True

dirIE=r"C:\\Assets\\IEDriverServer.exe"
ie_service = IEService(executable_path=dirIE)
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=ie_service, options=ie_options)

url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/inputs"
print("Aqui Va 1")
driver.get(url)
print("Aqui Va 2")
```